# Mapping through a object that is the only object in an array of list (nested object)

Tags: reactjs, api

Im having a hard time mapping through an object in an array. So i have this code and im able to display the array but the comments (object) is not showing. that is im not able to access my nested object. I have scouted the internet and all the solutions there havent helped me. Any ideas or push to the right direction is greatly appreciated

```js
function SingleTweet() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const [single, setSingle] = useState({})
  const { id } = useParams()
  useEffect(() => {  axios.get(`https://localhost:44368/api/users/${id}`).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data, "list of heroes  ");
      setSingle(res.data);
    });
  }, []);
  const [coms, setCom] = useState({})
  useEffect(() => { axios.get(`https://localhost:44368/api/comments/${id}`).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data, "list of Comments  ");
      setCom(res.data);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <LeftSidebar />
      <div>
        <div>
          <h2>Home</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="post-1">
          <div>
            <Avatar src={single.profilePicture} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <h3>
                  {single.name}
                  <div>
                    @{single.userName}
                  </div>
                </h3>
              </div>
              <div className="post_headerDesription-1">
                <p>{single.post}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src={single.image} alt="" />
            <div className="p_footer">
          <Tweet />
          <RepeatIcon />
          <FavoriteBorderIcon />
          <PublishOutlinedIcon />
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
{/* i want to display the comments here that belong to the post */}
   </div>
  <RightSidebar />
</div>
  )
}
```

this is my console log of the api call

```
comments: (2) [{…}, {…}]
id: 1
image: "https://media2.giphy.com/media/Q2tS8xloz0cg0/giphy.gif"
name: "Robin"
post: "Batman said i couldnt go out tonight :("
profilePicture: "https://variety.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Robin.jpg?w=681&h=383&crop=1"
userName: "robin"
```

Comment: So you just want to display the values of your `coms` variable?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to display it, the two comments

Comment: just to clarify things up, is that coms value is array? because the default value of your state is an object `{}`, if that's an array, it should be `const [coms, setCom] = useState([])`.